# Layout OK in Firefox, Safari & Chrome but not IE

Tags: html, css

New to HTML/CSS but have had training; based on my trainer's designs built a site that looks OK in Firefox, Safari & Chrome but IE everything goes out of the window! Would appreciate help on either how to fix it, or where I could look to get more info on where I'm going wrong. Many thanks.
http://www.mandolinjack.com

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mandolinjack.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Which IE? What is the problem? Any code?

Comment: The `<div>` containing the logo image isn't closed, but instead you're closing a `</p>`. Start with fixing it

Comment: Instead of only posting a link to your website it is much more appreciated if you post the samllest part of hml and css that demonstrates your problem and add that to your question, if possible supported by a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please share some code samples. Be specific of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you're having problems with IE is because your site makes IE go into Quirks Mode.

Quirks mode is a very old backward-compatibility mode that is built into IE. It causes the browser to render the page quite differently to normal, and it also switches off a *lot* of the newer features in the browser. You therefore want to avoid quirks mode at all costs.

The reason you're in quirks mode is because you haven't put a doctype declaration at the top of your page. If you don't specify the doctype, IE defaults to quirks mode.

If you're not sure what the above paragraph means, that's fine; just add the following line to the top of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...right at the top, above the `<html>` tag. That should solve most of the problems.

You should also run your page through the official [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) to check if you have any other errors in your HTML code, and fix anything that it finds.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd like to add, right at the top means first line first character, not second line. It's a common mistake ...